# Jhipster Prod build getting Failed

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, jhipster

I tried using "mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests" command to run the prod build for generating WAR file

This is the error I am facing:

```
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    [INFO] npm ERR! errno 2
    [INFO] npm ERR! DocScore@0.0.0 webpack: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"`
    [INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 2
    [INFO] npm ERR!
    [INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the DocScore@0.0.0 webpack script.
    [INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    [INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\LenovoWin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-25T07_40_41_872Z-debug.log
    [INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    [INFO] npm ERR! errno 2
    [INFO] npm ERR! DocScore@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
    [INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 2
    [INFO] npm ERR!
    [INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the DocScore@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
    [INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    [INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\LenovoWin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-25T07_40_42_317Z-debug.log
    [INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    [INFO] npm ERR! errno 2
    [INFO] npm ERR! DocScore@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
    [INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 2
    [INFO] npm ERR!
    [INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the DocScore@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
    [INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    [INFO] npm ERR!     C:\Users\LenovoWin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-25T07_40_42_438Z-debug.log
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  12:48 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-25T13:10:42+05:30
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (webpack build prod) on project docscore: Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

These are the versions I am Using:

- Node v12.13.0
- NPM 6.13.0
- jhipster 6.5.1

Comment: There is not enough information to help you, there is probably some useful error logged before what you pasted. Is this the first time you run a prod build? Does it fail also when not using maven and running 'npm run webpack:prod'?

Comment: It fails while running 'npm run webpack:prod' also

Comment: Fine so please edit your question to paste full output and learn to  use block formatting as I did when I edited your question otherwise it's unreadable.